# Criticism: Act Or Statement?

Tags: word-meaning

I have a question about the [definition](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/criticism?q=criticism) in this dictionary for the noun "*criticism*":

> the ***act*** of expressing disapproval of somebody/something and opinions about their faults or bad qualities; a ***statement*** showing disapproval

What is the difference between "*the act of expressing disapproval*" and a "*statement showing disapproval*"?  Is a "*statement*" an act?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are two separate definitions that are closely related. Perhaps the two definitions will become more clear when used in a sentence.

> the act of expressing disapproval of somebody/something and opinions about their faults or bad qualities

Example: "Criticism is a useful tool for inspiring cultural change."

This one describes the concept of criticizing things at large, like the word "physics" can describe the field of study or concept of physics.

> a statement showing disapproval

Example: "I don't need your criticism; it's not like you're well-versed on the subject."

Comment: Or, "The criticism he received was overwhelming." In this case it is the fact of being criticized rather than the actual statements which hurt.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe the lexicographers are trying to distinguish between is the act of criticizing, which will always involve some form of *speech-act* (broadly conceived, so that a political cartoon would fall under the rubric, as would "performance art" and any other human activity involving the use of signs and symbols) and a textual or other physical representation of the act.

**John Doe's stinging criticism of federal housing policy has politicians ruffled. They do not react well to criticism.**

**Have you read John Doe's criticism of federal housing policy in the latest *Policy Wonk Gazette*?**